# Returning from a loop in groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy

i'm trying to get all of the array selected to be returned but 
return breaks the loop, not allowed to use println etc, Its an array inside of an array called from a website, it only prints the first element then the loop breaks. Any help appreciated

```
def String citylist(String[][]data){                                
String result = null; 
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){                    
        result = data[i][0];
        return result;                               
    }           
}
```

Comment: Can you explain again what you're trying to do?  The code you posted will just return the first element of the first array.  You also don't need `def` in the method definition.  You also don't need the variable `result`, you could just `return data[i][0]` instead.  You also don't need semi-colons `;`

Comment: Sorry, it has to use def as i have to use a function, as i am calling the function through a JOptionpane. All i know is when its run i need the first element of each array. also the semi colons are because i move on to java soon, sorry if its not worded well i'm a bit confused. Ideally i need it to return it each element on its own line.

Comment: You don;t need to use the `def` ...  _"as I have to use a function"_ makes no sense...  WHat you have there is a method.  Without the `def` it's still a method

Comment: I think what @tim_yates is saying is that def and String are redundant. The return type is either def or String, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first element of every array, this is what you need to do:

```
String[] citylist(String[][] data) {
    String[] result = new String[data.length]
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result[i] = data[i][0]
    }
    return result
}
```

I was not sure wether your method signature is correct or not, so I changed it to return an `array` of `String`. But if you want a `String` you can do:

```
String citylist(String[][] data) {
    String[] result = new String[data.length]
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result[i] = data[i][0]
    }
    return result.toString()
}
```

Same think if you can use a `List`:

```
def citylist(String[][] data) {
    def result = []
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result << data[i][0]
    }
    return result
}
```

And then you can even use some nice Groovy features:

```
def citylist(String[][] data) {
    def result = []
    data.each { 
        result << it[0]
    }
    return result
}
```

For all above code the result will be `[1, 11, 21]`

If I understand your last comment, this is another way to do:

```
String[][] citylist(String[][] data) {
    String[][] result = new String[data.length][]
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result[i] = new String[1]
        result[i][0] = data[i][0]
    }
    return result
}
```

Your result will be `[[1], [11], [21]]`

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "it has to be in a function" as the other answer uses a function, so please let me know if you need something different ;)

Comment: It works, however do you know how to change it from it returning in the format [0,1,2 .....] to in a column so one on each line ?

Comment: If you mean to keep an 2d array then I edited my response.

Comment: i tried it and it got an error, i think i do mean to keep it 2d, i need it to print it in a column ?

Comment: sorry result was my mistake, you most recent edit fixed it thank you very much

Comment: please don't use patterns like `def result = []; x.each{ result << it ]` - there is `collect` for that.  Also there is an superfluous `it` in the line with the `each`.

Comment: I think that first `cityList` method which has the signature `String[] citylist(String[][] data)` could be simplified to 1 line of code... `data*.getAt(0)`.

Comment: Yeah or `data*.first()` while we are golfing

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess you want the first element of every array...  it's hard to tell from the question...

If that's the case, you can do:

```
List<String> citylist(String[][]data){                                
    data.collect { it[0] }
}
```

Comment: yeah sorry that's what i meant, but it has to be in a function, thank you for the help

Comment: That is a function...  No idea what you're on about